# Issue while upgrading the Magento Instance Upgrade

Tags: magento2, magento-upgrade, composer-update

I am currently having the issue, while magento instance upgrade, while running composer upgrade i am having the require resources to be available. But here question is i already having one version of required

```
Problem 1
    - cache/cache 0.4.0 requires league/flysystem ^1.0 -> satisfiable by league/flysystem[1.0.0, 1.0.0-alpha1, 1.0.1, 1.0.10, 1.0.11, 1.0.12, 1.0.13, 1.0.14, 1.0.15, 1.0.16, 1.0.17, 1.0.18, 1.0.19, 1.0.2, 1.0.20, 1.0.21, 1.0.22, 1.0.23, 1.0.24, 1.0.25, 1.0.26, 1.0.27, 1.0.28, 1.0.29, 1.0.3, 1.0.30, 1.0.31, 1.0.32, 1.0.33, 1.0.34, 1.0.35, 1.0.36, 1.0.37, 1.0.38, 1.0.39, 1.0.4, 1.0.40, 1.0.41, 1.0.42, 1.0.43, 1.0.44, 1.0.45, 1.0.46, 1.0.47, 1.0.48, 1.0.49, 1.0.5, 1.0.50, 1.0.51, 1.0.52, 1.0.53, 1.0.54, 1.0.55, 1.0.56, 1.0.57, 1.0.58, 1.0.59, 1.0.6, 1.0.60, 1.0.61, 1.0.62, 1.0.63, 1.0.64, 1.0.65, 1.0.66, 1.0.67, 1.0.68, 1.0.69, 1.0.7, 1.0.70, 1.0.8, 1.0.9, 1.0.x-dev, 1.1.0, 1.1.1, 1.1.2, 1.1.3, 1.1.4, 1.1.5, 1.1.6, 1.1.7, 1.1.8, 1.1.9, 1.x-dev] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
```

But other resource require same league/flysystem of different version i.e

```
"league/flysystem": "^2.4",
```

So Kindly please provide solution, that What should i have to make it solve. so that my magento instance successfully upgraded.

Answer (score 1):

Composer will not let you install conflicting requirements like this. Your options are:

- Remove the package that requires `"league/flysystem": "^2.4",`
- Try and install a version of the conflicting package that requires `league/flysystem` at a suitable version for your Magento instance (`^1.0`)
- Try and install `league/flysystem` version as an alias? I wouldn't recommend this, there is a reason why composer will not let you install conflicting packages like this.

Comment: I have followed your comments and tried same but even those below errors showsup.
#composer update
Problem 1
- magento/product-community-edition 2.4.3-p1 requires league/flysystem ^2.0 -> satisfiable by league/flysystem but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
# composer require league/flysystem --no-update
Using version ^2.4 for league/flysystem
./composer.json has been updated
# composer update
 Problem 1- cache/cache 0.4.0 requires league/flysystem ^1.0 -> satisfiable by league/flysystem but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.